# How to get site collection url using javascript?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am stuck up in a requirement where i need to get the site collection url to pass in a function.
Please help?

Comment: What is a "site collection url"?

Comment: @Armin -- google it. Vinod -- you need to explain where you're having a problem.

Comment: Are you kidding? It is not me, who has a question about it! But maybe I should open a question on stackoverflow ;-)

Comment: Armin, this is SharePoint specific (and, if you work in that field, it is a very common term). Since the post was tagged with "SharePoint", there is no need to explain it in the question.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `L_Menu_BaseUrl` variable, it is set automatically by some of SharePoint's default scripts.

You can find more information about it here

- http://vrdmn.blogspot.com/2011/08/javascript-lmenubaseurl-varaible-for.html
- http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2009/05/18/determine-the-url-of-sharepoint-web-services-using-jquery-javascript.aspx

Comment: Important to note that L_Menu_BaseUrl provides only a relative location of the current site / subsite you are in. It does not necessarily reflect the site collection URL.

Answer (score 2):

you have 2 options:
1) in your javascript use the L_Menu_BaseUrl variable. it contains the relative url of the site collection
2) if you need the absolute url you can use the following javascript code snippet in the server control:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var siteUrl = "<%= SPContext.Current.Site.Url %>";
</script>
```

It renders absolute url to the site collection. the approach (2) allows you to form up the url you need on the server side.

I hope you got the idea.
Good luck.

Comment: or SP.ClientContext.get_current().get_url()

Comment: +1 thanks, I didn't know you could just include controls in script blocks

Comment: Code block are rarely allowed, so alternative 2 usually doesn't work.